# How can I use vim to replace literal "\n" with literal "\\n"?

Tags: c++, regex, vim, newline

Currently, I have a C string defined as this:

```
std::string str = "printf(\"Hello world\n\")";
```

The outer most double quotes are for this string. As we can see the double quotes inside the string have been escaped by `\`.

When I used `fprintf()` to write the above string to file, I saw `\n` was treated as a newline, but it turned out `\\n` will solve this problem.

There are many literal `\n` in this file. I tried `%s/\n/\\n/g` in vim, but even the real "newlines" are affected.

How should I just replace the literal `\n` to `\\n` in vim, without affecting the real newline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to replace all literals `\n` with literal `\\n` then use the command:

```
:%s/\\n/\\\\n/g
```

That is, each *backslash* has to be individually *escaped*.

---

The string

```
std::string str = "printf(\"Hello world\n\")";
```

will result in

```
std::string str = "printf(\"Hello world\\n\")";
```

and no real *newlines* will be replaced.

Comment: since the search term is entirely used in replacement section, can simplify it to `:%s/\\n/\\&/g`

Answer (score 2):

C++11 has introduced raw strings which are extremely handy in such cases.

```
std::string str = R"(printf("Hello world\n"))";
```

See reference of [string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) form (6).